# Use XMLReader in C# to read a php file

Tags: c#, php, xml, xmlreader

How would I go about using XmlReader in C# to read in a php that someone else has written that returns an XML document. Using .Create("PathToPHP.php") fails to work as I think it is just reading in the php document. I can post source code to the C# that I have if I am thinking about what Create actually does wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP document needs to be hosted on the server in order to output the HTML. If you are reading it like .Create("C:\MyXMLoutput.php"), it's not going to work because it is being accessed directly, therefore it is just like any other text file.

However, if you are accessing your PHP like .Create("http://urltophp.com/MyXMLoutput.php") it will work. It means you are asking the Webserver to parse the PHP code for you and return the output (which will be xml).

To validate the output, try opening the URL to the PHP in your browser and see it's output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it solidfies what is actually the problem here. The script is on the server but its output is not in an XML format in a web browser. The pages source is however. I guess a sub question would be... Is there a way to pull the source into XmlReader? Because I don't think there is without me actually building the document in the C# program which would require tons of rewrite :(.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the definition or XML Structure in the PHP file. to test that, what you can do is copy some or all of the source of the file to a local file and try reading that as XML.

If that doesn't work then check if the file's schema is like the one mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp

Comment: Now I am super confused because Notepad ++ says there are no syntax errors with the XML plugin on ALL of the source of that page... It is throwing System.Xml.XmlException on a line and position that just has a hyphen there... Well I think I got my answer though I appreciate it I will have to contact the person who made this script for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it helped you out